# Terraform script empty azurerm automation variable when encrypted flag true

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have a problem when accessing azure automation account variable if the encrypted flag is true. Value is empty. Here are the steps:

Step 1:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_variable_string" "db-password" {
    name = "test-database-password"
    resource_group_name = var.rgr-initial
    automation_account_name = var.aut-acc-name
    value = "bhdc3tSLZjZUcVj8"
    encrypted = true
}
```

Step 2:

```
data "azurerm_automation_variable_string" "database-password-var" {
name = "test-database-password"
resource_group_name = var.rgr-initial
automation_account_name = var.aut-acc-name
}
```

Step 3:

```
password = data.azurerm_automation_variable_string.database-password-var.value
```

If the flag encrypted is false the I am able to get the value. If it is true and the value is encrypted, it comes empty.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I also noticed that all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not onlly a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances of your issues being actually answered.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Comment: Yep, found out that this is due azure behavior. Did use a key-vault for the purpose instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you **can't read encrypted value** by design. From [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/variables?tabs=azure-powershell):

> You **can't** use this [Get-AzAutomationVariable] cmdlet to **retrieve the value of an encrypted variable**. The only way to do this is by using the internal Get-AutomationVariable cmdlet in a runbook or DSC configuration. For example, to see the value of an encrypted variable, you might create a runbook to get the variable and then write it to the output stream: